# Methodology for admin panel testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

I am currently working on an admin panel project and workng with a freelancer for it. He is using bootstrap theme, php and mysql. We are about to end the project and I want to test it befor I get it but I am very unexperienced on testing.

My first question is what kind of testing methods should I apply on it (security, ui)? 
Secondly since it requires username and password, what type of automated testing methods can I apply on it?

Comment: Well, since you are about to end the project, I'd say you are in big troubles. For the next project I'd recommend you to start testing on the very first day of development. In this case, I'd probably go for high-level functional tests to make sure your project works according to customer requirements.

Comment: But how about now? what tool can I use?

Answer (score 0):

1/ Security :
- Make sure that the php entities are filtered using server side encoding functions otherwise it may be get vulnerbale to sql injection and it allows the attacker to access the admin previleges (read more about : broken authentication via sql injection )

- Make sure to make the login mechanism is not using 302 redirection otherwise the attacker could stop the redirection and access your admin panel (read more on : https://medium.com/@mustafakhan_89646/asuss-admin-panel-auth-bypass-af5062584ddf )
- Make sure to include the sessions & cookies on every functions on the admin source code scripts or the attacker could cause unprevileges actions on the admin side (e ,g : IDOR , sqli via directory bruteforcing )

for the second question i didn't understand what you want to do ,
so if you didn't understand me take a look at the words between () haha